# What is this item and why would it be in-line in a starter

Tags: voltage

Is this item a resistor, transistor, capacitor? What is it and most importantly, why would it be inline in the power wire between the "start" position of a switch and the starter on my generator?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a "polyfuse" of some sort (self-resetting current limiter). But that style of component is intended to be mounted on a rigid PCB of some sort, not free-hanging in a wiring harness. Its leads will fail rapidly from fatigue caused by movement and vibration.

Comment: My guess also: polyfuse (self -resetting fuse for overcurrent protection)

Comment: Tack it to something solid with some quality silicone adhesive, leads also. It's hard to tell, does it have a missing lead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found on google:
"Resettable Fuse K30-U300" It is a PTC.

[image]

[Translated web page](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fproduct.dzsc.com%2Fproduct%2F804857-20140616165850020.html&edit-text=)

If the intention is to protect something critical I would probably replace it with a cable mounted fuse holder. Like this: [image]

Comment: I expect it's an attempt to prevent/reduce over-long-cranking given the described location in-line with the starter. Not clear that a normal fuse would be an improvement there.

Answer (score 1):

It is re-settable fuse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse
It acts like low value resistor until current is low. If too much current is passed through the device, it will heat up. When hot its properties changes so its resistance becomes high, effectively blocking high current. When high current is removed it will cool down and return to low resistance.

Pros against regular fuse is automatic recovery when short-circuit or similar condition is removed.

Speed of reaction is dependent of current. The more current over the declared, the faster it will increase its resistance.

Comment: Makes sense... As a starter, it'd heat up as it is used and "pop" when the starter has been run too long, stopping a possible overuse of the starter.

Comment: Yes. Also if motor is blocked it would draw too much current, so it prevents fail of it.